# How to add class to a button inside div of class="demo" using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add class to the button inside div using Javascript.

```
 <div class="demo">
     <button>Inquire Now</button>
 </div>
```

I want to add class **popupnew** to the button with reference to the demo class using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//javascript
var d = document.getElementById("btn");
d.className += "popupnew";


//or jquery

$().ready(function() {
  $(".demo button").addClass('popupnew1');
});
```

```css
.popupnew {
  color: red;
}

.popupnew1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="btn">Inquire Now</button>
</div>

<div class="demo">
  <button>Inquire Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `d.className += "popupnew";` will not add space(required) in between class names...

Comment: Also note that `$().ready()` is not a valid handler. Use either `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){})`

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
document.querySelector( ".demo button" ).classList.add( "popupnew" );
```

Explanation

- Access the element using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- Add class using [classList.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

**Demo**

```js
document.querySelector(".demo button").classList.add("popupnew");
```

```css
.popupnew {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <button>Inquire Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. If I want to append class in the button if there are some classes present there. @gurvinder372

Comment: Is that a new question, then please post it separately with relevant code?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at (index):214 @gurvinder372

Comment: @Rahgav I have added a demo.